# Use contextmanager inside init

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-3.5, contextmanager

In the code below I don't understand why the `with super().__init__(*args, **kwargs):` line in MyFileIO2 is throwing an error about missing `__exit__` while everything works perfectly fine with the MyFileIO class. I don't really understand what exactly the difference between doing the with inside or outside of the init is. Can someone enlighten me what is going on here?

```
import io

class MyFileIO(io.FileIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = super().__enter__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('first byte of file: ', f.read(1))
        return f

class MyFileIO2(io.FileIO):
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = super().__enter__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('first byte of file: ', f.read(1))
        return f

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with super().__init__(*args, **kwargs): # AttributeError: __exit__
            pass

path = 'some_file.bin'

with MyFileIO(path, 'rb'):
    pass

MyFileIO2(path, 'rb')
```

Comment: I think this would've raised `AttributeError: __enter__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call the context manager on `self`, because `__init__` doesn't actually return anything.

```
class MyFileIO2(io.FileIO):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        with self:
             pass

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = super().__enter__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('First byte of file: ', f.read(1))
        return f
```

For testing, I created a binary file having the contents "hello world".

```
_ = MyFileIO2(path, 'rb')    
# First byte of file:  b'h'
```

---

What happens is the return value of `super().__init__` is being passed through the context manager, so you effectively have this:

```
with None:
     pass

AttributeError: __enter__
```

The context manager tries calling the `__enter__` method on the `NoneType` object, but that is an invalid operation.